# Silent install of Microsoft eval software

Tags: windows-7, ms-office, silent-installer

I am looking to automate the setup of lab computers for a conference. When doing this manually we would install in demo mode, but given that I am one person setting up 40 machines with a very short window to do so, I would like to automate the process. My question is, is there a way to automate Office 2013 in demo mode? I have the demo download, but when I use the /admin flag with setup.exe I get an error that components are missing, which has me worried that Microsoft has gimped the demo download. Given that the download is for IT professionals this seems unlikely however, as testing deployment scenarios would be exactly the kind of thing we need the demo for. So hopefully I am missing something new and obvious.

Additionally, we often get machines from the local vendor with a mix of OSs, and given that the labs are already time constrained to cover the lab topic, supporting OS training is not an option, so I would like to be able to also install Windows 7 in demo mode, at least until Windows 10 arrives and allows for a newer OS without so much need for remedial training before it can be used. The last time I did silent installs of an OS was Windows XP, so any direction to some more recent resources on the topic would be greatly appreciated. If it makes a difference, I will have all resources on a Synology NAS, no Windows server or domain, and all lab machines will be on a workgroup.

Comment: do you have the full version setup? If so if you configure office for kms use and don't have one I think it might just start in demo mode. For windows it works for sure. Just use a normal installation disk and don't specify the key and it will be in evaluation mode. The most basic unattended mode for windows installations is a dvd (or usb drive) with the iso and an "autounattend.xml" file. The detailed description for this is documented here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349348%28v=ws.10%29.aspx but you can google there are lots of easier examples and tools for that

Comment: I thought I had the full version setup, but when I used the /admin flag it said it was missing things. But I'll give it another go. Just reassuring that it at least is possible. I have to be ready for the first conference in just four weeks, and just heard from one instructor that he also needs visual studio, local installs of IIS and certain admin tools available to all users. If I can nail all this it is going to be a real coup for me. ;)

Comment: If the machines are all identical and don't use some sort of unique ids you could of course also prepare one and capture an image once it is as you want it. Hard to say if this is the better option for you, depends on lots of factors really

Comment: I suspect that is the ideal that we will rarely see. We just hope to get all desktop machines. Getting all the same graphics cards and such is nearly impossible. And Autodesk software (the real topic of the conference)  is VERY finicky about cards and drivers. I'm trying to automate what I can to buy myself one night for all the stuff I can't. Previously a group of three or four people pulled an all nighter and barely had time for a basic install. And of course sometimes the software conflicts session to session, so we need to react to that as well. Gonna be a fun pilot I am sure.